# What name goes into the iphone app

Tags: ios7, xcode5, bundle-identifier

I am just going to submit my iPhone app. I have the app name given as Xyz-Pq and the bundle name as com.company.xyzpq. I want to know once the app is published and when the user install s it, it will go as Xyz-Pq or xyzpq as mentioned in bundle. Kindly confirm if anyone knows before i can proceed to uploading the binary and oblige.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app's home screen name will be **Xyz-Pq**.

You should be installing your app onto a device for testing prior to submission anyway, at which point you'll be able to confirm this.